# How can I stop avoiding poor WiFi automatically?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, android-versions

I have a Motorola G second gen(2014) and I was searching everywhere for a way to stop avoiding poor WiFi automatically by the phone, but I can't find it in my old phone. The option was there in my phone when it was running Kit-Kat 4.4., but I've recently updated my phone to lollipop and I can't find this setting anywhere. Please help.

Comment: If you go to settings>wifi>advanced you don't see anything there that says "Avoid unstable connections"?  I don't have Lollipop so I don't know for sure.

Comment: According to this article, this option has been disabled in Lollipop. [Lollipop Wi-fi Advanced Settings Missing "Avoid poor connections" and "Wi-fi priority"](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81843)

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Someone [previously posted](http://web.archive.org/web/20150316104840/https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100295/how-can-i-turn-off-the-setting-that-disconnects-me-from-poor-wifi) in this current thread [that screenshot](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=818430048000&name=HdpxL.jpg&token=ABZ6GAf4BIm9E07CDbTwyggcSMEjaKcm0g%3A1429598903261&id=81843&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAd1E1K_oV0jU1vbvpPgPOsJBDLgeg%3A1429598903261&inline=1) showing a device apparently running Lollipop (according to the graphic appearance) with that option present. That indicate that not *all* Lollipop based devices have lost that setting.
Unfortunately, the post have been suppressed and I'm a unable to know on which device this was.

Answer (score 0):

Check your WiFi setting for wifi plus. Wifi + switches between wifi and mobile data for the best connection to internet/data.